# how to integrate toast prive into nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3, primevue

I'm using the primeVue library. I have not used nuxt before and this component worked for me.
I registered it as a plugin in main.ts like this.

```
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice"
app.use(ToastService)
```

How can I get it to work in nuxt?
It immediately throws out the error No PrimeVue Toast provided! as soon as I try to call useToast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define a nuxt plugin before using `"primevue/toastservice"`

add a plugin `plugins/primevue-toastservice.ts` first

```js
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ToastService);
});
```

now you can use it

read the [nuxt3 plugins document](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins) for more details